# Python splitting with string as delimiter

Tags: python, split, file-writing

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
AAACAACAGGGTACAAAGAGTCACGCTTATCCTGTTGATACT
TCTCAATGGGCAGTACATATCATCTCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAAAACGTGTGCATGAACAAAAAA
CGTAGCAGATCGTGACTGGCTATTGTATTGTGTCAATTTCGCTTCGTCAC
TAAATCAACGGACATGTGTTGC
```

And I need to split it into the "non-N" sequences, so two separate files like this:

```
AAACAACAGGGTACAAAGAGTCACGCTTATCCTGTTGATACT
TCTCAATGGGCAGTACATATCATCTCT

AAAACGTGTGCATGAACAAAAAACGTAGCAGATCGTGACTGGC
TATTGTATTGTGTCAATTTCGCTTCGTCACTAAATCAACGGACA
TGTGTTGC
```

What I currently have is this:

```
UMfile = open ("C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\sequence.txt","r")
contignumber = 1
contigfile = open ("contig "+str(contignumber), "w")

DNA = UMfile.read()
DNAstring = str(DNA)

for s in DNAstring:
    DNAstring.split("NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN",1)
contigfile.write(DNAstring)

contigfile.close()
contignumber = contignumber+1
contigfile = open ("contig "+str(contignumber), "w")
```

The thing is that I realize there is a linebreak between the "Ns" and that is why it is not splitting my file, but the "file" I'm showing is just a part of a much much bigger one. So sometimes the "Ns" will look like this "NNNNNN\n" and sometimes like "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n", yet there is always a count of 1000 Ns between my sequences that I need to split.

So my question is: How do I tell python to split and wite into different files every 1000xNs knowing that there will be different number of Ns in each line?

Thank you all very much, I really have no informatics background and my python skills are at best basic.

Comment: How long is the string? Can you read it all at once and remove the linebreaks, or do you _have_ to read it line by line?

Comment: if you can read it at once, `re.findall(r'[ACGT]+', DNAstring.replace('\n', ''))` should make the trick.

Comment: Is the pattern always that each input file will contain exactly two sequences separated by NNNNNs?

Comment: @martineau - I doubt it - OP says "the "file" I'm showing is just a part of a much much bigger one".

OP - you might need to think about how to do this if the file is so big you can't load it in as one big string, although if you find it can't - that's probably a new question...

Comment: I doubt I can do it in a single string. The file is a 43Mb txt file. It actually contains around 15,000 sequences separated by Ns

Comment: @manuelmm90: A Python string has an overhead of 24 bytes, but apart from that, each byte in the file takes up one byte of RAM, so you should easily be able to read a 43MB into a single string on a modern computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split your string on `'N'` and then remove all the strings that are empty, or just contain a newline. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

DNAstring = '''AAACAACAGGGTACAAAGAGTCACGCTTATCCTGTTGATACT
TCTCAATGGGCAGTACATATCATCTCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAAAACGTGTGCATGAACAAAAAA
CGTAGCAGATCGTGACTGGCTATTGTATTGTGTCAATTTCGCTTCGTCAC
TAAATCAACGGACATGTGTTGC'''

sequences = [u for u in DNAstring.split('N') if u and u != '\n']

for i, seq in enumerate(sequences):
    print i
    print seq.replace('\n', '') + '\n'
```

**output**

```
0
AAACAACAGGGTACAAAGAGTCACGCTTATCCTGTTGATACTTCTCAATGGGCAGTACATATCATCTCT

1
AAAACGTGTGCATGAACAAAAAACGTAGCAGATCGTGACTGGCTATTGTATTGTGTCAATTTCGCTTCGTCACTAAATCAACGGACATGTGTTGC
```

The code snippet above also removes newlines inside the sequences using `.replace('\n', '')`.

---

Here are a few programs that you may find useful.

Firstly, a line buffer class. You initialise it with a file name and a line width. You can then feed it random length strings and it will automatically save them to the text file, line by line, with all lines (except possibly the last line) having the given length. You can use this class in other programs to make your output look neat.

Save this file as `linebuffer.py` to somewhere in your Python path; the simplest way is to save it wherever you save your Python programs and make that the current directory when you run the programs.

**linebuffer.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Text output buffer 

    Write fixed width lines to a text file

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.03.23
'''

class LineBuffer(object):
    ''' Text output buffer

        Write fixed width lines to file fname
    '''
    def __init__(self, fname, width):
        self.fh = open(fname, 'wt')
        self.width = width
        self.buff = []
        self.bufflen = 0

    def write(self, data):
        ''' Write a string to the buffer '''
        self.buff.append(data)
        self.bufflen += len(data)
        if self.bufflen >= self.width:
            self._save()

    def _save(self):
        ''' Write the buffer to the file '''
        buff = ''.join(self.buff)

        #Split buff into lines
        lines = []
        while len(buff) >= self.width:
            lines.append(buff[:self.width])
            buff = buff[self.width:]

        #Add an empty line so we get a trailing newline
        lines.append('')
        self.fh.write('\n'.join(lines))  

        self.buff = [buff]
        self.bufflen = len(buff)

    def close(self):
        ''' Flush the buffer & close the file '''
        if self.bufflen > 0:
            self.fh.write(''.join(self.buff) + '\n')
        self.fh.close()


def testLB():
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    fname = 'linebuffer_test.txt'
    lb = LineBuffer(fname, 27)
    for _ in xrange(30):
        lb.write(alpha)
    lb.write(' bye.')
    lb.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testLB()
```

Here is a program that makes random DNA sequences of the form you described in your question. It uses `linebuffer.py` to handle the output. I wrote this so I could test my DNA sequence splitter properly.

**Random_DNA0.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Make random DNA sequences

    Sequences consist of random subsequences of the letters 'ACGT'
    as well as short sequences of 'N', of random length up to 200.
    Exactly 1000 'N's separate sequence blocks. 
    All sequences may contain newlines chars 

    Takes approx 3 seconds per megabyte generated and saved 
    on a 2GHz CPU single core machine.

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.03.23
'''

import sys
import random
from linebuffer import LineBuffer

#Set seed to None to seed randomizer from system time
random.seed(37)

#Output line width
linewidth = 120

#Subsequence base length ranges
minsub, maxsub = 15, 300

#Subsequences per sequence ranges
minseq, maxseq = 5, 50

#random 'N' sequence ranges
minn, maxn = 5, 200

#Probability that a random 'N' sequence occurs after a subsequence
randn = 0.2

#Sequence separator
nsepblock = 'N' * 1000

def main():
    #Get number of sequences from the command line
    numsequences = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 2
    outname = 'DNA_sequence.txt'

    lb = LineBuffer(outname, linewidth)
    for i in xrange(numsequences):
        #Write the 1000*'N' separator between sequences
        if i > 0:
            lb.write(nsepblock)

        for j in xrange(random.randint(minseq, maxseq)):
            #Possibly make a short run of 'N's in the sequence
            if j > 0 and random.random() < randn:
                lb.write(''.join('N' * random.randint(minn, maxn)))

            #Create a single subsequence
            r = xrange(random.randint(minsub, maxsub))
            lb.write(''.join([random.choice('ACGT') for _ in r]))
    lb.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Finally, we have a program that splits your random DNA sequences. Once again, it uses `linebuffer.py` to handle the output.

**DNA_Splitter0.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Split DNA sequences and save to separate files

    Sequences consist of random subsequences of the letters 'ACGT'
    as well as short sequences of 'N', of random length up to 200.
    Exactly 1000 'N's separate sequence blocks. 
    All sequences may contain newlines chars 

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.03.23
'''

import sys
from linebuffer import LineBuffer

#Output line width
linewidth = 120

#Sequence separator
nsepblock = 'N' * 1000

def main():
    iname = 'DNA_sequence.txt'
    outbase = 'contig'

    with open(iname, 'rt') as f:
        data = f.read()

    #Remove all newlines
    data = data.replace('\n', '')

    sequences = data.split(nsepblock)

    #Save each sequence to a series of files
    for i, seq in enumerate(sequences, 1):
        outname = '%s%05d' % (outbase, i)
        print outname

        #Write sequence data, with line breaks
        lb = LineBuffer(outname, linewidth)
        lb.write(seq)
        lb.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The thing is, that there are some Ns on the ACTG sequences too. I need to split only where there are specifically 1000 Ns (there are ocasionally a string of 200 Ns here and there). 

Yes the file does open, I just edited the name for the sake of the question, but I'll edit it back to make it clearer, thx.

I seem to get the writing right, it is the splitting I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @manuelmm90 Oh. That makes things a little trickier. I'll add some new code to my answer.

Comment: Very nice detail for the linebuffer.py  :)

Comment: @manuelmm90: Thanks! I'm surprised I hadn't written one before, although I do have a rather neat word-wrapping class. :) For all I know, it might've been possible to do the linebuffer simpler & more efficiently using the [io](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) module; I really need to get around to studying that module & exploring its possibilities...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace every N and \n with a space, and then split.

```
result = DNAstring.replace("\n", " ").replace("N", " ").split()
```

This will give you back a list of strings, and the 'ACGT' sequences will also be split with every new line.

if this is not you goal an you want to conserve the \n in the 'ACGT' and not split along it, you can do the following:

```
result = DNAstring.replace("N\n", " ").replace("N", " ").split()
```

this will only remove the \n if it is in the middle of an N sequence.

**To split your string exactly after 1000 Ns**:

```
# 1/ Get rid of line breaks in the N sequence
result = DNAstring.replace("N\n", "N")
# 2/ split every 1000 Ns
result = result.split(1000*"N")
```

Comment: The 'ATCG' sequences also contain newlines.

Comment: The thing is, that there are some Ns on the ACTG sequences too. I need to split only where there are specifically 1000 Ns

Comment: Though this give anidea of how to have the 1000N string without the \n and just use the 1000Ns as delimiter. Thx!

Comment: @devhallo: Your new code won't work properly if the 1000-N sequences contain runs of multiple newlines (i.e. sequences of `\n`). Hopefully, that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can read the whole file at once

```
s=DNAstring.replace("\n","")         # first remove the nasty linebreaks
l=[x for x in s.split("N") if x]     # split and drop empty lines

for x in l:                          # print in chunks
    while x:
        print x[:10]
        x=x[10:]
    print                            # extra linebreak between chunks
```

Comment: FWIW, a chunk size which is a multiple of 3 is probably more appropriate than 10 here, since these are DNA base sequences. See [DNA codons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table).

Comment: Thx, they are nasty those line breaks :)